# How to increase precision up to 18 decimals after decimal point in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-cell-format

I want to have a number like this in my cell, 18 decimals after decimal point:

> 10.643958132611619777

But Google Sheets rounds it down to 13 decimals

> 10.6439581326116

How can I increase precision in Google Sheets?

"Increase decimal places" button just adds trailing zeros, which is not good:

[image]

> 10.6439581326116**00000**

Comment: Google sheets numbers are decimal type up to 15 digits. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44534232/14246120

Comment: @Oleg_S  Since an answer from StackOverflow doesn't count as a duplicate, perhaps it would be more useful if your comment was posted as an answer. It would also be more helpful for future users looking for an answer. (Just a thought).